# PHPUnit Selenium 2 extension setting cookies

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to set cookies before test but for some reason they are not set.

Here is my example code:

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://dev.local/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $session = $this->prepareSession();

        $session->cookie()->remove('language_version');
        $session->cookie()->add('language_version', 'en')->set();
        $this->url('/');

        $this->assertEquals('Title in English', $this->title());
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question in Selenium documentation:

> If you are trying to preset cookies before you start interacting with a site and your homepage is large / takes a while to load an alternative is to find a smaller page on the site, typically the 404 page is small (http://example.com/some404page)

Now my tests look something like this:

```
$this->url('/unit_tests.php');
$this->cookie()->remove('language_version');
$this->cookie()->add('language_version', 'en')->set();

$this->url('/');
$this->assertEquals('Title in English', $this->title());
```

The `/unit_tests.php` is an empty PHP file that lets me initially set the cookie for the page.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie shouldn't exist so the remove will fail. Selenium runs the browser with a new empty profile on each run of a test suite.
.

Comment: removing a non existent cookie actually does not raise any exceptions.

Comment: But it may be silently ignoring the rest of the code. Try adding a log or alert right after the remove cookie to see if it is running the following code.